# Selenium - login by google account (blank, white window)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with my automation test in Selenium. I want to test login by google account.

Here are steps:

1. Click on login button to google account (new window appear)
2. Enter email and click next button
3. Enter password and click next button
4. And here I have a problem, because after enter the password and click next button, I have just blank, white window

Additional information:

- I have the newest selenium version, WebDriver and browser (Chrome)
- Test worked fine about 2 months ago
- Manual login by google account works fine for this email and password
- The same problem with automation test occur for the other test data
- I have no error in browser console

Maybe someone had a similar problem and can help me :)

**screenshot - blank, white window**

[image]

EDIT:

my driver version:
[driver version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXYpE.png)

At this moment I can't paste my code here, because of copyright, but I will try to rewrite it and paste here.
I have wait in my test. If I tried refresh a page after timeout, I had error 400 in this blanket window.

Comment: Please post your entire test code that we can help you better.

Comment: Your binary versions please

Comment: Please tell us also what you already have done to fix this. My first idea (only assumption) is that you need to wait for the website to load or anything in the background is waiting for something. If you ran in a timeout, try to make a refresh.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads - Refer that link ChromeDriver 2.38 - Chromedriver crash/lose connection when navigating to Gmail has resolved on the latest version. Might be you need to update your chrome browser to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, new chrome version (66.0.3359.139 64-bit) fix the problem